# What happens when I upvote a "possible duplicate" comment

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I can see that if I flag a question as duplicate it up-votes existing "possible duplicate" comment, so my question is if I up-vote an existing "possible duplicate" comment, does it mean that my flag quota also decrements?